# Does SQLite come with PHP Version 5.4.9 out of the box?

Tags: php, sqlite

I am new to php ...
I am using this code:

```
$db = new SQLite3("f");
```

Can I be sure that SQLite is packaged with php so no separate installation of SQLite is needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFM to the rescue!

> The SQLite3 extension is enabled by default as of PHP 5.3.0. It's possible to disable it by using `--without-sqlite3` at compile time.
>
> Windows users must enable `php_sqlite3.dll` in order to use this extension. This DLL is included with Windows distributions of PHP as of PHP 5.3.0.
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.installation.php